# How to prove (-b)(-d)=bd?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, analysis

George Peacock proved this by the so-called "[Principle of the Permanence of Equivalent Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_peacock#Algebraic_Theory)"

Detailed as below:

> Because *(a-b)(c-d)=ac-ad-bc+bd* holds for positive integers (that is
>   **general** form with ***specific*** values), it should still hold for all type of values (that is **general** form with ***general***
>   values)
>
> So, let *a=0* and *c=0*, we have *(-b)(-d)=bd*.

But I just read that there's [flaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_peacock#Algebraic_Theory) about this principle.

So how to prove this? Or should it be proved?

### ADD 1

Today, I found more references to my question:

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Hankel):

> Fischbein notes that he solved the problem of products of negative
>   numbers by proving the following theorem: "The only multiplication in
>   R which may be considered as an extension of the usual multiplication
>   in R+ by respecting the law of distributivity to the left and the
>   right is that which conforms to the rule of signs."

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number):

> In mathematics, a negative number is a real number that is less than
>   zero. Negative numbers represent opposites. If positive represents
>   movement to the right, negative represents movement to the left. If
>   positive represents above sea level, then negative represents below
>   level. If positive represents a deposit, negative represents a
>   withdrawal. They are often used to represent the magnitude of a loss
>   or deficiency. A debt that is owed may be thought of as a negative
>   asset, a decrease in some quantity may be thought of as a negative
>   increase.

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number#Multiplication):

> Multiplication
>
> When multiplying numbers, the magnitude of the product is always just
>   the product of the two magnitudes. The sign of the product is
>   determined by the following rules:
>
> ```
> The product of one positive number and one negative number is negative.
> The product of two negative numbers is positive.
> ```
>
> Thus
>
> ```
> (−2) × 3  =  −6
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> (−2) × (−3)  =  6.
> ```
>
> The reason behind the first example is simple: adding three −2's
>   together yields −6:
>
> ```
> (−2) × 3  =  (−2) + (−2) + (−2)  =  −6.
> ```
>
> The reasoning behind the second example is more complicated. The idea
>   again is that losing a debt is the same thing as gaining a credit. In
>   this case, losing two debts of three each is the same as gaining a
>   credit of six:
>
> ```
> (−2 debts ) × (−3 each)  =  +6 credit.
> ```
>
> The convention that a product of two negative numbers is positive is
>   also necessary for multiplication to follow the distributive law. In
>   this case, we know that
>
> ```
> (−2) × (−3)  +  2 × (−3)  =  (−2 + 2) × (−3)  =  0 × (−3)  =  0.
> ```
>
> Since 2 × (−3) = −6, the product (−2) × (−3) must equal 6.

Comment: There are many ways to define a binary operation $*$ such that  $b*d=bd$ when $b,d$ are non-negative, and $|b*d|=|(-b)*(-d)|$  for all $b,d$. But if we  also want $*$ to distribute over $+$ we must  have $(-b)*(-d)=bd.$

Answer (score 2):

Use the distributive law.

$(-a)(b+(-b)) =(-a)(b)+(-a)(-b)=-(ab)+(-a)(-b)=0$

$(-a)(-b)=ab$

Comment: Now you just need to prove that $(-a)b = -(ab)$, which is as easily done using the distributive law ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First prove that $-a = (-1)\cdot a$ and then use that multiplication is commutative and that $(-1)\cdot(-1) = 1$.